# Map not showing colors when using HighCharts with Map plugin

Tags: svg, highcharts, highmaps

As can be seen at the following url http://www.highcharts.com/studies/map-from-svg.htm, when rendering a map with Highmaps from SVG the color range is no longer working on the map. Instead all countries/continents are the same color.

I do know for a fact that this used to work correctly as I have a working version locally with an older version of the maps plugin 'Map plugin v0.1 for Highcharts'. However when I upgrade my Highcharts version and Map plugin then it no longer works as expected.

With the newer api for HighMaps plotOptions.map.colorRange no longer seems to exist.

I have also tried colorAxis with dataClasses and min/max but this does not work either. In fact I can't find an example where this works while using an SVG instead of .js map file.

If there is a way to do this with the new HighMaps please help.

Comment: Colors are based on data, but there is no data, so there is only one color. If you add value variables per data point it will be colored accordingly to the options set to colorAxis. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/9jgxf60p/

Comment: Will check this out on Monday. Are you sure this will still work with an SVG map? As in your fiddle you are using http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=us-population-density.json&callback=?

Comment: Kacper thanks very much for your help. I have managed to get it working. It seems with the older map.js plugin it used to work with '"data": [
   {
    "name": "mg",
                                 y: 0.91,
    "path": "M823,-18'}].  By just changing the 'y' to 'value' the problem is solved.